# Duplicate column issue in migration scripts in .net microservice module. I have to resolve duplicate column in my migration which already executed

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, microservices, entity-framework-migrations

In .net core microservices, another team works on open source modules, and I extend their modules in my project. I already added one column in a Entity and then same column is added by open source team. Now duplicate column error is showing.
I can not alter open source migration files and my column is already in production.
How to resolve this issue please suggest.

Comment: Drop/Delete your existing column !?

Answer (score 0):

i think we are dealing with multiple smells here.

1. each microservice should have its own Datarealm
2. by the sound of it you extended a Table of an object which was generated by the opensource service

But this does not help you, the question is can you merge the Data which is in this column.

If so you might get away with a simple copy/update.
What you need todo is:

1. Create a new Column With a different Name
2. Copy your existing Data into the new column
3. Drop your column
4. Execute your Migration
5. Copy your Data back into the column
6. Test your application very carefully, if the logic which you have implemented for the from you generated Data works as intended
7. Drop your backup column

Depending on the amount of Data this will lead to a downtime, so plan ahead and have a rollback strategy ready if something goes wrong.

***Personal Opinion to Prevent those Smells***

Every time i needed an opensource project in my projects in the past i wrote a wrapper around it, this has multiple benefits.
For one if the api of the project changes you only have to update it in exactly one place, which improves the maintainability.

Because it has a wrapper it automatically gets a own Database and if i need to extend an entity which i get from one of those opensource projects, i usually do it via Foreign Keys with a different Table. Which then gets linked via a view.

Yes this costs some performance, but in the end it was worth it every time.